# MFC Draw Stuff Outside OnPaint in a Dialog-based App

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc

I'm currently trying to draw something outside OnPaint function. I know there are many duplicate questions on the internet, however, I failed to get any of them to work. This is entirely because of my lack of understanding of MFC.

What works inside OnPaint:

```
CDC* pDC = GetDC();
HDC hDC = pDC->GetSafeHdc();
CRect lDisplayRect;
GetDlgItem(IDC_DISPLAYPOS)->GetClientRect(&lDisplayRect);
GetDlgItem(IDC_DISPLAYPOS)->ClientToScreen(&lDisplayRect);
ScreenToClient(&lDisplayRect);
pDC->FillSolidRect(&lDisplayRect, GetSysColor(COLOR_3DDKSHADOW));
pDC->TextOutW(300, 300, TEXT("test"));
```

It fills the area of the button control I have with a defined colour.
And it prints out the "test" string without any issue.

But it won't work outside OnPaint.

I've seen numerous suggestions such as using CmemDC,CPaintDC, etc
But none of them worked outside OnPaint.

For example,

```
CClientDC dc(this);
dc.rectangle( ....);
```

does not work.

Please note that this is a temporary test code and what I am eventually trying to do is draw incoming frames from a frame grabber within my display thread (a separate thread from the main UI thread) on the DisplayPos area and my dlg object(the dialog) owns an instance of the DisplayThread class. And I'm passing HWND and displayrect upon creating the member mDisplayThread so I can draw stuff within the display thread and that's the reason why I need to be able to draw to DC outside OnPaint (DisplayThread class does not have OnPaint or inherit any class that has it).

I'm in dire need of help...Please help!

Added: I have overridden PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg) and made it return without calling the default function just in case WM_ERASE msg is erasing everything, but this approach didn't work either.

Comment: Easiest way is to set up the data for what you want to draw.  Then [InvalidateRect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-invalidaterect) the region you want for the drawing.  This will then post a WM_PAINT message and you just draw as normal.  This also handles the re-drawing case when another window temporarily hides your window and you need to redraw it when it is eventually uncovered.  Flicker-less and frequent updates need a different technique but from the question I don't think you are doing this.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by set up the data. I have the data already ready to be drawn. I'm trying to draw this data onto the DC which will be obtained from a HWND that's passed to an instance of another class.

Comment: _"...set up the data..."_ provide the data to the class doing the drawing.  You also need to cope with the re-drawing case (outlined above) which means the data needs to persists for lifetime of the window.

Comment: Inside `OnPaint()` (which is mapped to `WM_PAINT`) you should use `CPaintDC` (which calls `BeginPaint()/EndPaint()`. The worker thread can store the data (for example the last frame retrieved) and invalidate the `IDC_DISPLAYPOS` control. This will trigger a `WM_PAINT` message (`OnPaint()`), which will be processed when the main thread is almost about to enter the idle state (it's a low-priority message). That is, the main thread is going to do the painting. Of course this is somehow "asynchronous" processing.

Comment: You can also draw directly from the thread, using the `GetDC()/ReleaseDC()` functions. This is called "drawing", rather than "painting". Drawing takes place immediately, bypassing the message queue. But you still need to process the `WM_PAINT` message, as painting requests may be the result of resizing, moving, unhiding the window, bringing it to the front etc etc, in addition to programmatically invalidating it. Check the documentation [**here**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/about-painting-and-drawing).

Comment: Thank you very much Richard and Constantine. Unfortunately no progress so far :( I have created another sample MFC app with a button ctrl and another btn ctrl for displaypos. I've tried
`CPaintDC dc(this); 
//everything else the same as the provided code above GetDlgItem(IDC_DISPLAYPOS)->Invalidate();
InvalidateRect(lDisplayRect,0);
`
This still won't print text or fill the rect. I'm honestly so confused 

Comment: A small progress here! Thanks everyone. Will update if there is more.
`HDC hdc = ::GetDC(this->m_hWnd);
::TextOut(hdc, 100, 100, TEXT("test"), 4);
::ReleaseDC(this->m_hWnd, hdc);
`
does the print job outside OnPaint().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example:

```
void CMFCApplicationDlg::OnLButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
    // TODO: Add your message handler code here and/or call default
    HDC hdc = ::GetDC(m_hWnd);
    Ellipse(hdc, point.x - 10, point.y - 10, point.x + 10, point.y + 10);

   ::ReleaseDC(m_hWnd, hdc);
    CDialogEx::OnLButtonDown(nFlags, point);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two important suggestions:

1. Do not draw outside of `OnPaint`. The content may be erased or painted over at the direction of OS.
2. Do not draw on the dialog surface. First, it is not designed for that. It may be affected by other controls or by theming, skinning, etc. Just create a window with your own window procedure, so you are in control.

I would store the information needed for drawing in you `frame grabber`, and cause an immediate window painting by calling [RedrawWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-redrawwindow)

Comment: A dialog is just a window. If it is supported to render onto a window, then so it is for a dialog. Of course you would want to make sure to not have any controls overlap your designated rendering area. But then, you would want to make that sure for a window as much as a dialog.

Comment: @IInspectable Re: `A dialog is just a window.` - I respectfully disagree. It is a window with a very specific window proc. Also, it is guaranteed to be at the bottom of Z-order.

Comment: A window is also at the bottom of the Z-order, relative to child windows (such as controls). A dialog has any window procedure you want it to have. With the exception of the way you return values from it, there is no difference. In this context, there is literally no difference between a dialog and any other window. If you want to disagree, make sure to provide rationale.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response and help. I'll have OnPaint responsible for for drawing or at least try my best to.